# Django Stateless API

Tags: django, api, stateless, stateful

I am trying to understand the excat meaning of stateless and found this in Google and I have a small doubt.

[image]

I have a Django API which **fetches some data from PostgreSQL** database and does some manipulations and returns it. How is this API stateless, as it is relying on external database?

Answer (score 0):

it means,

that thought you have authenticated your self to the web server on http protocol from your browser or device, you have to reauthenticate your self every time you make a http request to the server from the same device or browser via the info saved as **cookie** on your browser (the **cookie** will be send to the server with the http request).

cookies make the http request state full

so the server relay on your cookie info in http protocal, not the browser or device(ip) info.

Comment: did not get you....so finally, my Django API is stateless or stateful?

Comment: if your api uses authentication system via cookies then it will be stateful.

Comment: I am using @login_decorator

Comment: so it is stateful.